# How to resume a lifecycle state through code?

Tags: java, android

I have an application in java, android studio.

This app will be used for a specific business purpose on a hardware (tablet) that will be dedicated solely to it(Users cannot close the app to make another use of the tablet).

I need to make sure the application is never closed ...

My first idea was to make the navigation bar never appear to the user, so he would not have the option to close.

I was unsuccessful, after a lot of research ... immersive mode, sticky immersive mode..I can even make it difficult to access the bar, but never deprive.

My idea now is to solve the problem through the application life cycle.

I want that when the onPause or onStop () method is called it will execute a code that retrieves the cycle to onStart ().

It's possible?
Is there any easier or better way to do it?

Comment: Keyword you're looking for is "Kiosk mode".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`KIOSK MODE`** to achieve this functionality in android, In **`KIOSK Mode`** it self use for **`COSU`** purposr(Corporate Owned Single Use application) or a Single-Use device.

Here is the step by step guide, which explain how to achieve this.

[COSU / KIOSK MODE](https://snow.dog/blog/kiosk-mode-android)

Comment: Yes it is Kotlin Code, you can use this also, or you can convert it into JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

4 Solutions you can try

1. Use a local broadcast receiver you can send a broadcast from `onPause or onStop () and start Activity you want
2. create a service which will bind to the activity and there you can monitor your activity
3. use alarm manager and start `onPause or onStop ()` and start your activity in when the alarm invokes
4. Use "Kiosk mode" to achieve this

`

Answer (score 0):

You can do in on 2 ways:

- Override `onStop()` , `onPause()` , `onDestroy()`. You can call methods you want or Intent to app again in these methods
- Use user background services for keeping the app alive

Have good coding

;))

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your application as launcher so that pressing home button or killing apps would return to your application. You can do it by declaring these two parameters in android manifest and then set your app as default launcher app in android system.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Add these categories to your AndroidManifest.xml inside activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the navigationbar might be solved using windowFocusChangeListener 
but i would like to recommend a probably better solution for you, you need to achieve what's called "Kiosk mode", please have a look at android's solution for that here https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices?hl=en
or maybe use a 3rd party app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock&hl=de